# Behavior of Oracle GoldenGate CSN when multiple replicas exist?

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

Need to get more details about Oracle GoldenGate CSN.

Following is the system architecture configured.

Source DataBase   - Oracle
Target DataBase - Oracle

For each table on souce database, 2 tables (BASE table and DELETE table) are defined on target database.
Configured 2 replicas to transfer data from source to target database. 
One replica moves the INSERT/UPDATES to target database and other replica moves the DELETE records to target.

Following is the view defined by GG which gives GoldenGate metadata information.

[GoldenGate metadata info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnXSb.png)

Row with servername ends with 'CRN01A' represents the GG replica for BASE table.
Row with servername ends with 'CRN01D' represents the GG replica for DELETE table.

APPLIED_LOW_POSITION gives  'All messages with commit position less than this value have been applied'.

Our question is if the both replicas will have their own isolated CSN or in synchronization with respect to extract.

Example:

1. APPLIED_LOW_POSITION initial value - 100 for both BASE table replica and DELETE table replica.
2. 100 INSERTS/UPDATES occured on source DB. BASE table replica APPLIED_LOW_POSITION value changed to 200.
3. After step2, 3 DELETEs occured on source system. Our question is at this point of time, what will be the APPLIED_LOW_POSITION value for DELETE replica?
   Will it be **103 or 203**?

Can you please provide your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The CSN counter is connected with the CSN number on the source database. It always grows.

If the CSN was equal 100, then some transactions (INSERT) have occurred. It grew to 200.

Then 3 additional DELETE operations were made. And from 200 it would grow to 203.

Those 3 DELETE operations may not be replicated to the INSERT/UPDATE target, so the APPLIED_LOW_POSITION may not change on this target and stay at the 200 level.

But on the DELETE target the APPLIED_LOW_POSITION would rise to 203.